# Can a field type detect if it's being edited inline in Craft 2.3?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

Is there was a way for a field type to detect if it is being instantiated for the inline editor or even the live preview? I am working on some responsive UI's to make Google Maps for Craft work optimally on all screen sizes, but current smaller screens are posing a problem. Obviously media queries are being used, but was also wondering if I could easily detect where the field type was being instantiated and then I could possible add additional classes to my field type wrapper.

Comment: Maybe this would be a good use for the Element Query Polyfill, so that the elements could adapt themselves to the size of their container rather than the viewport? https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

Comment: I was already thinking the same thing, but the for sake of knowing I was just wondering if this was technically possible to detect in some way without using a size to determine it. And just to clarify, "viewport" was using in the same way you were using "container". Container is probably better wording for it.

Comment: I think size detection is the better way to do it, Justin. Keep in mind that the Live Preview pane is resizable!

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the whole request is Live Preview using [`craft.request.isLivePreview`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#isLivePreview).

Comment: What about the inline editing modal? That was the primary question, the live preview was an additional example of what I was asking since it was conceptually the same thing.

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood the question. :-/ still a bit unfamiliar with the plugin side of Craft

Answer (score 2):

You would do that with JS, at least this is how it is done to the core fields (see [MatrixInput.js](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/8ea72d1e5503e3ed11aac86fb972eb1fac92e54b/app/resources/js/MatrixInput.js) line 152 ff.).

Just check for the container width of your field and then swap your classes / do your responsive design magic.